# Relative file path of a XML Schema in visual studios project

Tags: c#, filepath, relative-path, fileinfo

I added a Xml Schema to my Visual Studio project called **"FaxTemplateXMLSchema.xsd"**
I'm now trying to reference that schema to do validation. I have a function that takes the filepath of a schema to reference it and validate, the only problem is I can't figure out the relative filepath. 
The full file path is **"C:\Users\ccoleman\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FaxTemplateConverter\FaxTemplateConverter\FaxTemplateXMLSchema.xsd"**
I'm attempting to not hardcode it in and would like to reference it something like this. 
`String schemaFile = "..\\FaxTemplateXMLSchema.xsd";`
if I use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` I get the network drive **"N:\**" and `Path.GetFullPath("FaxTemplateXMLSchema.xsd")` gets me **N:\FaxTemplateXMLSchema.xsd**
Edit: I ended up just adding string in the resources that is easily changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make it deployment agnostic, the something like

Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)

will give you the folder your code is executing from then work out where you want to be from there.

Comment: Okay now I'm confused relative path from where? The file is deployed along with the executable?

Comment: Relative from the executable, however the template wasn't getting deployed along. I found a different solution to fix this and now I just can edit a resource string to change the filepath.